# How to deal with some ambiguous context free grammar productions in Python

Tags: python, pipe, nltk, context-free-grammar, chomsky-normal-form

I am trying to use CNF grammar by feeding nltk.cfg with a bunch of grammar productions like:

```
 NN -> 'rubble' | 'slope' | 'Jake'
 VP -> V NP | VP PP
```

But it has problem (gives the error: Expected an arrow) with the productions which have pipes on the left-hand side of the production. Example:

```
VP | <VBP-SBAR> -> VBP SBAR
```

Does nltk have any grammar-method which doesn't have problem with pipes on the left-hand side?

If not, How can I change all those productions to usable productions like the first group? Example:

```
VP  -> VBP SBAR    
<VBP-SBAR> -> VBP SBAR
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A production rule with multiple options on the left-hand side of the production is no longer a Context Free Grammar - there must be only one nonterminal on the LHS of every rule.

Well, it doesn't really make any sense, in the first place, if you can split the rule

```
VP | <VBP-SBAR> -> VBP SBAR
```

into two rules

```
VP -> VBP SBAR
<VBP-SBAR> -> VBP SBAR
```

Comment: Why it doesn't make sense? Doesn't it mean that either of the rules on the LHS can end up with the RHS?

Comment: Sure, but it's not a context free grammar anymore, which has that rule that only one nonterminal can be on the LHS.